# ClassNotFoundException Attempted to load class "RajaOngkirLib" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement?

Tags: php, web, prestashop-1.7

Is anyone can help me to solve my problems? im really new to php

i always get this error message when i try to purchase from my shop.

Im using API Shipping module From KurirQ

[everytime i click purchase on my shop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSDci.png)

[I always get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlbsO.png)

---

Here are the Codes

[CODES1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwEJw.png)
[CODES2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSeK7.png)

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: where is the file for the class `RajaOngkirLib` located? Inside that file, does it have a namespace declared at the top? If so, what is said namespace?

Comment: Hello sir , i already attach the codes , below , im a little bit confused right now

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Comment: Yes, I saw your code and inside it you have `$rj = new RajaOngkirLib();` but you haven't declared the class anywhere. You may find http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php will help you.